# MultiDatesPicker en un componente Joomla?

Tags: jquery, joomla3

Lo que quiero es cargar en una vista de un componente de Joomla un multidate picker, mi codigo es este:

```
<php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
  $document = JFactory::getDocument();
  JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
  JHtml::_('jquery.ui');
  $document->addScript( "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" );
  $document->addScript('https://github.com/dubrox/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/blob/master/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js');
?>
<script>
$('calendar').multiDatesPicker({
          dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", 
          beforeShowDay: function(date) {
              var Highlight = SelectedDates[date];
              if (Highlight) {
                  return [false, "Highlighted", Highlight];
              }
              else {
                  return [true, '', ''];
              }
          }
      });
</script>

<form method="post">
  <input  id='calendar' name='boton_fechas[]'/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Sin embargo donde debería aparecer el calendario aparece vacío.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden. También es importante que traduzcas la pregunta ya que te encuentras en un lugar de habla hispana